# How to fix EACCES issues with npm install

Tags: npm

Some of my node modules get installed but there are always these sort of issues on this particular linux mint machine

```
npm install 

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, open '/home/me/.npm/semver/3.0.1/package/package.json'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, open '/home/me/.npm/semver/3.0.1/package/package.json']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/home/me/.npm/semver/3.0.1/package/package.json',
npm ERR!   parent: 'gulp' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

Answer (score 76):

This code fix it for me.

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Comment: I've looked at multiple answers for this, and this is the only one that has worked for me

Comment: FYI, just running the first command solved the problem for me on WSL. However, I also had to follow the instructions here subsequently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29468404/gyp-warn-eacces-user-root-does-not-have-permission-to-access-the-dev-dir?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: I thought about doing this but didn't want to give ownership of those folders to any user who happened to run this script.

Comment: Likely also needs `sudo chown -R \`whoami\` /usr/local/bin` for global modules with binaries.

Answer (score 13):

UPDATE. See 
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29787502/1614973)
for a better way.

---

You have to set correct permissions (ownership) so `npm` can access your (sub)directories with your normal user permissions:

```
sudo chown -R $USER <directory>
```

where in your case `<directory>` is `/home/me` and `-R` is for recursive to also change ownership of all your subdirectories, which is exactly what you want. That should fix the `EACCESS` issue.

Sadly the advise to run the command as `root/Administrator` is wrong here.

You want to **avoid** running `npm` with `sudo` ever, as [recommended by the `npm` creator Isaac Schlueter](http://foohack.com/):

> **I strongly encourage you not to do package management with sudo!** Packages can run arbitrary scripts, which makes sudoing a package manager command as safe as a chainsaw haircut. Sure, it’s fast and definitely going to cut through any obstacles, but you might actually want that obstacle to stay there.

[See here for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29787215/1614973).

Comment: Great advice. I might just add - probably not a good idea to run this on your whole `/usr` directory, at least not on MacOSX, as this can then cause further issues. (See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22329005). I would recommend running it on the lowest level possible, for your `npm install` command to work. Personally I ran it on `/usr/local/lib/node_modues` and it worked fine after that.

Answer (score 5):

Add sudo before npm install . It will permit access to write .

`sudo npm install [name of package]`.

Comment: Not the best option. And anyway, this has already been mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score 3):

in windows run cmd as administrator and then try:

```
npm install -g <package-name>
```

in mac os or linux try:

```
sudo npm install -g <package-name>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use "sudo npx create-react-app app-name"
it may still show error because some dependencies may be mising but a directory and the necessary files maybe created.

Answer (score 1):

Set the correct permission to access the necessary directories.

In my case (`Node` & `NPM` Installation via `Brew`) on `BigSur`:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /Users/YOUR_USERNAME/node_modules
```

Comment: I was able to solve my issue using this code. Is this method considered safe, or does it have the same concerns as using `sudo`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are still facing problem after running :

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Run the npm install command with :

```
--unsafe-perm
```

which will help you in installing the package with out any problem.

Answer (score 1):

To minimize the chance of permissions errors, you can configure npm to use a different directory. In this example, you will create and use hidden directory in your home directory.

Back up your computer.

On the command line, in your home directory, create a directory for global installations:

```
mkdir ~/.npm-global
```

Configure npm to use the new directory path:

```
npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
```

In your preferred text editor, open or create a ~/.profile file and add this line:

```
export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
```

On the command line, update your system variables:

```
source ~/.profile
```

To test your new configuration, install a package globally without using sudo:

```
npm install -g jshint
```

(ref: https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally)

Answer (score 1):

Running the code in sudo mode have fixed the problem for me

`$ sudo npm install -g nativefier`

And if you have related issues like package unmet dependencies check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26571326/how-do-i-resolve-the-following-packages-have-unmet-dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

I understand one might be suspicious about changing the ownership of folders situated in the system files. But it's completely safe, they are meant to host processes that you can use without sudo. So I prefer this solution because it's good and will guarantee compatibility after.

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/bin
sudo chmod -R 0775 /usr/local/bin

sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules
sudo chmod -R 0775 /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

If you installed a new version of node.js, you could still get some error. Try deleting the npm cache:

```
sudo npm cache clear
```

Answer (score 0):

To permanently fix this problem, please run:

```
sudo chown -R 1000:1000 "/home/$USER/.npm"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo npm install -g create-react-app
```

just adding `sudo` before `nmp install` will give superuser privilages to run npm and that would not cause any erros while it want to alter a file or access it. well, i hope this might help you!

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include an explanation of how this works and why it is the solution to the problem described in the question. See [answer]. Especially as just adding `sudo` before what is shown in the question does not result in the code you show here. Please also consider to explain the difference to other existing older and similar answers.

Comment: I didn't dare to try `sudo` myself, although it seems like it should work for most people in most cases. Simply adding `sudo` to force run commands that previously failed due to lack of permission is very risky, security-wise, because if a malicious software manage to sneak itself to run along with the command somehow, it would have permission to access our system's files. I have managed run `npm install -g ...` without needing `sudo` while setting up a new computer not long ago, so unless someone has a tight deadline to deliver a project, I advise *against* trying this at all.

Answer (score -1):

I had the Similar Problem when I typed:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

The Terminal replied:

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
....
```

So I add "sudo" like This:

```
sudo npm install -g create-react-app
```

And problem Solved!! :-)
(So I am agree with "chethan chandan" about using "sudo")

Answer (score -1):

After I run the following code:

```bash
sudo npm config set global = false
```

I came across the problem:

```bash
$ npm install -S cors               
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cors
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cors'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cors'] 
...
```

And I set it back, by using this command:

```bash
sudo npm config set global = true
```

And then, I can install packages successfully with npm. Hope it will help.