# can not run the npm cmmand

Tags: linux, node.js, shell

I'm confused by this problem
My OS is
CentOS 7
my account can exec sudo

I download the nodejs node-v0.10.31-linux-x64.tar.gz for 64-bit linux from the official nodejs site and put it under the /usr/tools, unzip the file  and then put the node path to PATH, the npm and node exec file is in the folder /usr/tools/node-v10/bin

the result like 
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/home/lawrence/bin:**/usr/tools/node-v10/bin**

I exec the command:
`sudo npm install -g bower` or  the `sudo npm install bower`
the error occurs:
*sudo: npm: command not found*

and when exec the command:
 `npm install -g bower` or  the  `npm install bower`
the error occurs like:

```
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/tools/node-v10/lib/node_modules/bower'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/tools/node-v10/lib/node_modules/bower']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/tools/node-v10/lib/node_modules/bower',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/tools/node-v10/lib/node_modules/bower',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/tools/node-v10/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23',
npm ERR!      '/usr/tools/node-v10/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:46:53',
npm ERR!      'Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.10.0-123.6.3.el7.x86_64
npm ERR! command "/usr/tools/node-v10/bin/node" "/usr/tools/node-v10/bin/npm" "install" "bower" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd /usr/tools/node-v10/bin
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.31
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.23
npm ERR! path /usr/tools/node-v10/lib/node_modules/bower
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/tools/node-v10/lib/node_modules/bower
npm ERR! fstream_type Directory
npm ERR! fstream_class DirWriter
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/tools/node-v10/lib/node_modules/bower'
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/tools/node-v10/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/tools/node-v10/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:46:53
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, open 'npm-debug.log'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, open 'npm-debug.log'] errno: 3, code: 'EACCES', path: 'npm-debug.log' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.10.0-123.6.3.el7.x86_64
npm ERR! command "/usr/tools/node-v10/bin/node" "/usr/tools/node-v10/bin/npm" "install" "bower" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd /usr/tools/node-v10/bin
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.31
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.23
npm ERR! path npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, open 'npm-debug.log'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /usr/tools/node-v10/bin/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: I guess that your `PATH` is changed after `sudo`. Have you checked the question [sudo changes PATH - why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257616/sudo-changes-path-why).

Comment: @user3584460 the project can work now but i don't know what causes this.seems boring using nodejs  and npm

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix EACCES issues with npm install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25290986/how-to-fix-eacces-issues-with-npm-install)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25290986/how-to-fix-eacces-issues-with-npm-install/