# How do I resolve `The following packages have unmet dependencies`

Tags: ubuntu, npm

I was using this script to install basic software, but had to interrupt because of slow internet speed.
Now when I hit `$ sudo apt-get install npm` , I get following error

```
yask123@yaskslaptop:~$ sudo apt-get installed npm
E: Invalid operation installed
yask123@yaskslaptop:~$ sudo apt-get install npm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 npm : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-abbrev (>= 1.0.4) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ansi (>= 0.3.0-2) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ansi-color-table but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-archy but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-block-stream but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-fstream (>= 0.1.22) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-fstream-ignore but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-github-url-from-git but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-glob (>= 3.1.21) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-graceful-fs (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-inherits but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ini (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-lockfile but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-lru-cache (>= 2.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-minimatch (>= 0.2.11) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-mkdirp (>= 0.3.3) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-nopt (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-npmlog but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-once but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-osenv but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-read but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-read-package-json (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-request (>= 2.25.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-retry but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-rimraf (>= 2.2.2) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-semver (>= 2.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-sha but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-slide but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-tar (>= 0.1.18) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-underscore but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-which but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Off-topic, try http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: I think this occurs because nodejs gets installed from deb.nodesource.com while npm comes from ubuntu. Usually mixing sources should be OK, but for some reason the nodesource versions don't get marked as fulfilling the npm dependancy. You can see this by comparing `apt-cache policy npm` with `apt-cache policy nodejs`. The aptitude answer worked for me, but it makes me nervous to mix apt and aptitude.

Comment: The comment of @Quantum7 must be the answer! I would defenitely vote up. It helped me to identify the problem. Removing `deb.nodesource.com` solves the error.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The command to have Ubuntu fix unmet dependencies and broken packages is

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

from the man page:

> -f, --fix-broken
>              Fix; attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place.
>              This option, when used with install/remove, can omit any packages
>              to permit APT to deduce a likely solution. If packages are
>              specified, these have to completely correct the problem. The option
>              is sometimes necessary when running APT for the first time; APT
>              itself does not allow broken package dependencies to exist on a
>              system. It is possible that a system's dependency structure can be
>              so corrupt as to require manual intervention (which usually means
>              using dselect(1) or dpkg --remove to eliminate some of the
>              offending packages)

Ubuntu will try to fix itself when you run the command.  When it completes, you can test if it worked by running the command again, and you should receive output similar to:

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.

Comment: in my case, `sudo apt-get -f remove` removed the broken package

Comment: Not working: E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Answer (score 186):

If `sudo apt-get install -f <package-name>` doesn't work, try **aptitude**:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude install <package-name>
```

Aptitude will try to resolve the problem.

As an example, in my case, I still receive some error when try to install `libcurl4-openssl-dev`:

```
sudo apt-get install -f libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

So i try aptitude, it turns out I have to downgrade some packages.

> ```
> The following actions will resolve these dependencies:
>
>     Keep the following packages at their current version:
>     1)     libyaml-dev [Not Installed]                        
>
> Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/? (n)
>
> The following actions will resolve these dependencies:
>
>     Downgrade the following packages:                                
>     1)     libyaml-0-2 [0.1.4-3ubuntu3.1 (now) -> 0.1.4-3ubuntu3 (trusty)]
>
> Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] (Y)
> ```

Comment: aptitude did the trick for me. Had to try a couple solutions down from the initial one, but it eventually got there. Great tip!!

Comment: aptitude may corrupt the whole system, using apt and aptitude together might remove all the packages if you are not using carefully enough!

Comment: I had a really messy dependency problem. Tried many commands with apt-get including -f install with no avail. The simple "sudo aptitude install" completely resolved the issue.

Comment: Enter '.' when asked "Accept this solution [Y/n/q/?]" to get next solution.

Comment: I had the same problem installing a lot of packages. This solution works. For all "Keep the following packages at their current version?", say "No". For all "Downgrade the following packages", say "Yes"

Comment: If you get `sudo: aptitude: command not found` error just install aptitude using `sudo apt-get install aptitude`

Comment: Aptitude not only fixed this issue, but many other dependency issues I had with my computer. Thank you very much

Comment: ```# aptitude install node-marked
…
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 node-marked : Depends: nodejs:any which is a virtual package, provided by:
                        - nodejs (12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3.1), but 18.17.1-deb-1nodesource1 is installed
                        - nodejs (12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3), but 18.17.1-deb-1nodesource1 is installed

The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     node-marked [Not Installed]                        
```

Answer (score 73):

First of all try this

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

If error still persists then do this

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Afterwards try this again:

```
sudo apt-get install npm
```

But if it still couldn't resolve issues check for the dependencies using `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and remove them one-by-one . Let's say dependencies are on npm then go for this ,

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
sudo apt-get remove npm
```

Then go to /etc/apt/sources.list.d and remove any node list if you have. Then do a

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then check for the dependencies problem again using `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and if it's all clear then you are done  .
Later on install npm again using this

```
v=8   # set to 4, 5, 6, ... as needed
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_$v.x | sudo -E bash -
```

Then install the Node.js package.

```
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

**The answer above will work for general cases also(for dependencies on other packages like django ,etc) just after first two processes use the same process for the package you are facing dependency with.**

Comment: Nodesource doesn't work for me; skipping  `curl -sL https://...` and just doing `sudo apt-get install -y nodejs works`

Comment: Went through it all, nothing worked, except the last bit of advice whereby removing nodesource.list from /etc/apt/sources.list.d fixed it all!

Comment: `rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list*` solved the issue. After, I could run `apt install npm` with success.

Comment: @Octave You are most welcome to edit the answer if required.

Comment: I would do it with pleasure but stackoverflow says there are too many pending edits for this answer. Will retry later.

Comment: My error was `The following packages have unmet dependencies: libwacom9 : Depends: libwacom-common (= 2.2.0-1) but 1.3-2ubuntu3 is to be installed E: Broken packages`. I followed these steps, and then reinstalled the `libwacom-common`

Answer (score 32):

I came to this situation when I installed node js from the latest stable release.

`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -`

It seems this version already comes with a prepackaged NPM. So when I tried to install NPM again, I got this error. If anyone is installing Nodejs in this manner then, it's not needed to install NPM separately.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 npm : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-abbrev (>= 1.0.4) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ansi (>= 0.3.0-2) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ansi-color-table but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-archy but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-block-stream but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-fstream (>= 0.1.22) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-fstream-ignore but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-github-url-from-git but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-glob (>= 3.1.21) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-graceful-fs (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-inherits but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ini (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-lockfile but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-lru-cache (>= 2.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-minimatch (>= 0.2.11) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-mkdirp (>= 0.3.3) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-nopt (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-npmlog but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-once but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-osenv but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-read but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-read-package-json (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-request (>= 2.25.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-retry but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-rimraf (>= 2.2.2) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-semver (>= 2.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-sha but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-slide but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-tar (>= 0.1.18) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-underscore but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-which but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: You deserve more likes!

Answer (score 22):

Installing nodejs will install npm ... so just remove nodejs then reinstall it:
    $ sudo apt-get remove nodejs

```
$ sudo apt-get --purge remove nodejs node npm
$ sudo apt-get clean
$ sudo apt-get autoclean
$ sudo apt-get -f install
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Answer (score 16):

I tried lots of method but below work like charm....

After this command run these :-

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x 565 | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Now check…

```
node -v
npm -v
```

Comment: I am using GCE (google compute engine) and this answer worked for me.

Comment: Me too, after having tried everything only this approach worked. And instantly.

Comment: This answer hard-codes a specific version. Check https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#debinstall for all available versions and the command line to install them.

Answer (score 9):

```
sudo apt install aptitude
```

Then

```
sudo aptitude install npm
```

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/978353/458947

Comment: I am using GCE (google compute engine) with an Ubuntu docker image and this worked for me. Please note you'll have to use `aptitude install -y npm` , while docker build or it will abort automatically.

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug in the npm package regarding dependencies :
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1088662/npm-depends-node-gyp-0-10-9-but-it-is-not-going-to-be-installed

Bugs have been reported.
The above may not work depending what you have installed already, at least it didn't for me on an up to date Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

I followed the suggested dependencies and installed them as the above link suggests:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs-dev node-gyp libssl1.0-dev
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install npm
```

Please subscribe to the bug if you're affected:

bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/npm/+bug/1517491
bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/npm/+bug/1809828

Comment: thanks so much of all this answers yours worked for me.

Comment: For me, I get:  E: Package 'libssl1.0-dev' has no installation candidate

Comment: That may have many causes, like no internet, no apt-update, different version of Ubuntu, etc. In Ubuntu 20.04 the package seems to be called libssl-dev . Try apt search libssl and see how yours may be named.

Comment: `E: Package 'libssl1.0-dev' has no installation candidate`

Comment: see reply above,search for the package name, it may be different

Answer (score 4):

First, run

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs-dev node-gyp libssl1.0-dev
```

then run

```
sudo apt install npm
```

Comment: how is this in any way an improvement to the answer above? It's a copy of my answer without explanation.

Comment: I needed `sudo apt-get install node-gyp`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on Pop OS:

Force an overwrite for the Node package (change nodejs_16.9.0-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb with your version):

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_16.9.0-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb
```

Fix the rest of the broken install:

```
sudo apt -f install
```

Make sure the rest of your system is properly up to date:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

credits to matigo :
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1362719/error-upgrading-nodejs

Comment: `--force-overwrite` helped in my case, also. This extreme step seems to be required from time to time for different packages. It was related to `libclang-common-15-dev` for me. I saw the solution via this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/266912/347966

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this issue. 
The problem was in version conflict. 
Nodejs 10 installed with npm. 
So before installing nodejs - remove old npm.
Or remove new node -> remove npm -> install node again.

This is the only way which helped me.

Answer (score 0):

What resolved it for me was:

```
$ apt update
$ apt install nodejs
```

I had `nodejs` installed from the official Debian repositories. This one was installed by `unattended-upgrades`. Before that it was installed from [NodeSource](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#deb). The one coming from NodeSource has `npm` in the `nodejs` package.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 22.04 has upgraded libssl1 to libssl3 so you need to add Ubuntu 21.10 source and force the installation of libssl1.

Try this on the terminal:

```
echo "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/impish-security.list

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libssl1.1
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you want to try this path https://gist.github.com/joulgs/c8a85bb462f48ffc2044dd878ecaa786
Here is how to install in ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 0):

somehow `sudo apt install apt` solved the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

I came across with the same problem. I followed the following steps for the solution: First I removed nodejs and npm. Then, using the information on the webpage "NodeSource Node.js Binary Distributions"  related with my operating system, I setup nodejs and npm. The webpage "NodeSource Node.js Binary Distributions" is in the following link:

https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md

The installation can be checked using the command given in the "Tests" section with the following link:

https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#tests

Answer (score 0):

I solved this like so:

```
  119  mkdir ~/.npm-global
  120  npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
  121  vi ~/.profile
    ## add .npm-global to start of your PATH var
  122  source ~/.profile
```

Then reinstall a new copy of npm in there:

```
npm install -g npm
```

That way, it wont use npm from `/usr/lib/node_modules` any more.

Also, if that doesn't work, make sure windows folders are not included in your linux PATH

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes dependencies cannot be installed since there are unknown to APT. In some scenarios, activating the universe repository can let APT know that this package is available to be installed.

---

To add the repo:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe && sudo apt update
```

Answer (score -7):

Node comes with npm installed so you should have a version of npm. However, npm gets updated more frequently than Node does, so you'll want to make sure it's the latest version.

Try

```
sudo npm install npm -g
```

Comment: I landed here while trying `sudo apt-get install -y nodejs npm`, (works fine for Ubuntu's default version of Node). All I had to do was `sudo apt-get install -y nodejs` instead and my `nodejs : Conflicts: npm` went away. Thanks for the hint!