# Unmet Dependencies When installing python-pip and python-dev

Tags: python

As be mentioned above, I tried to install python-pip and python-dev with command:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev
```

then I get:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev
[sudo] password for tailongnguyen: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
python-dev : Depends: python (= 2.7.11-1) but 2.7.12-1 is to be installed
python-pip : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
          Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
          Recommends: python-all-dev (>= 2.6) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: python-setuptools but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: python-wheel but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What I need to do now?
I tried

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

but it didn't help

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install -f` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26571326/how-do-i-resolve-the-following-packages-have-unmet-dependencies

Comment: I tried but the error still occurs

Answer (score -1):

See this link. This resolved this issue, though I got similar issue with apache2.2-common after fixing this.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/275861/problem-installing-python-dev