# The following packages have unmet dependencies: postgresql-9.6

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

Please help, I'm trying to install a fresh install of postgres-9.6 and only that version, but I keep receiving this error when I try to run:

> sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.6

```
dominic@dom-Inspiron-7559:~/Desktop/Projects/stemletics/stemletics/mysite$ sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.6Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql-9.6 : Depends: postgresql-client-9.6
                  Recommends: postgresql-contrib-9.6 but it is not going to be installed
 postgresql-contrib-9.3 : Depends: postgresql-9.3 (= 9.3.24-1.pgdg14.04+1) but 9.3.19-0ubuntu0.14.04 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I've tried 4 different guides on purging postgres from my computer and manually ran rm commands on postgres folders. I'm not sure what else I can do.

> dominic@dom-Inspiron-7559:~/Desktop/Projects/stemletics/stemletics/mysite$
>   postgres -vThe program 'postgres' is currently not installed. You can
>   install it by typing: sudo apt-get install postgres-xc

This is what is what i received after running the following command:

> sudo  apt-get autoremove postgresql*

```
part of this was removed
Package 'postgresql-9.3-pgfincore' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.3-pgmemcache' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.3-pgmp' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.3-pgpool2' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.3-pgq-node' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.3-pgq3' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.3-pgrouting' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.3-pgrouting-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.3-pgrouting-scripts' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.3-pgtap' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.3-pldebugger' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.3-pllua' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.3-plproxy' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.3-plr' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.3-plsh' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.3-plv8' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1-scripts' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.2' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.2-scripts' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.3' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.3-scripts' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.4' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.4-scripts' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.3-postgis-scripts' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.3-prefix' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.3-preprepare' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.3-prioritize' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.3-python-multicorn' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.3-python3-multicorn' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.3-reorg' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.3-repack' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.3-repmgr' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.3-repmgr-dbg' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.3-similarity' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.3-slony1-2' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.3-toastinfo' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-amcheck' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-asn1oid' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-citus' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-dbg' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-debversion' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-dirtyread' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-hll' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-hypopg' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-ip4r' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-jsquery' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-mimeo' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-mysql-fdw' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-numeral' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-orafce' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-partman' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-pg-checksums' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-pg-qualstats' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-pg-stat-kcache' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-pgespresso' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-pgextwlist' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-pgfincore' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-pglogical' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-pgmemcache' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-pgmp' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-pgpool2' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-pgq-node' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-pgq3' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-pgrouting' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-pgrouting-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-pgrouting-scripts' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-pgtap' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-pldebugger' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-pllua' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-plproxy' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-plr' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-plsh' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-plv8' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1-scripts' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.2' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.2-scripts' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.3' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.3-scripts' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.4' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.4-scripts' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-postgis-scripts' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-powa' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-prefix' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-preprepare' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-prioritize' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-python-multicorn' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-python3-multicorn' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-reorg' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-repack' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-repmgr' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-repmgr-dbg' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-similarity' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-slony1-2' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-toastinfo' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-unit' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.4-wal2json' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-amcheck' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-asn1oid' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-bgw-replstatus' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-citus' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-cron' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-dbg' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-debversion' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-dirtyread' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-hll' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-hypopg' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-ip4r' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-jsquery' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-mimeo' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-mysql-fdw' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-numeral' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-orafce' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-partman' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-pg-checksums' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-pg-qualstats' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-pg-stat-kcache' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-pgaudit' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-pgespresso' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-pgextwlist' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-pgfincore' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-pgl-ddl-deploy' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-pglogical' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-pgmemcache' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-pgmp' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-pgpool2' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-pgq-node' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-pgq3' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-pgrouting' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-pgrouting-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-pgrouting-scripts' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-pgtap' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-pldebugger' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-pllua' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-plproxy' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-plr' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-plsh' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-plv8' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-postgis-2.2' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-postgis-2.2-scripts' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-postgis-2.3' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-postgis-2.3-scripts' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-postgis-2.4' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-postgis-2.4-scripts' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-postgis-scripts' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-powa' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-prefix' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-preprepare' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-prioritize' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-python-multicorn' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-python3-multicorn' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-repack' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-repmgr' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-repmgr-dbg' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-similarity' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-slony1-2' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-toastinfo' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-unit' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.5-wal2json' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-amcheck' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-asn1oid' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-bgw-replstatus' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-citus' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-cron' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-dbg' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-debversion' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-dirtyread' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-hll' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-hypopg' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-ip4r' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-jsquery' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-mimeo' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-mysql-fdw' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-numeral' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-orafce' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-partman' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-pg-checksums' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-pg-qualstats' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-pg-stat-kcache' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-pgaudit' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-pgextwlist' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-pgfincore' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-pgl-ddl-deploy' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-pglogical' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-pgmemcache' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-pgmp' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-pgpool2' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-pgq-node' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-pgq3' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-pgrouting' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-pgrouting-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-pgrouting-scripts' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-pgtap' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-pldebugger' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-pllua' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-plproxy' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-plr' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-plsh' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-plv8' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-postgis-2.3' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-postgis-2.3-scripts' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-postgis-2.4' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-postgis-2.4-scripts' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-postgis-scripts' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-powa' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-prefix' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-preprepare' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-prioritize' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-python-multicorn' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-python3-multicorn' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-repack' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-repmgr' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-repmgr-dbg' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-rum' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-similarity' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-slony1-2' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-toastinfo' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-unit' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-9.6-wal2json' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-all' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-client' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-client-10' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-client-8.4' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-client-9.0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-client-9.1' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-client-9.2' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-client-9.4' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-client-9.5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-client-9.6' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-contrib' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-contrib-8.4' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-contrib-9.0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-contrib-9.1' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-contrib-9.2' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-contrib-9.4' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-contrib-9.5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-contrib-9.6' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-doc-10' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-doc-8.4' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-doc-9.0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-doc-9.1' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-doc-9.2' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-doc-9.3' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-doc-9.4' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-doc-9.5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-doc-9.6' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-filedump' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-mysql-fdw-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-pgsphere' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-plperl-10' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-plperl-8.4' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-plperl-9.0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-plperl-9.1' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-plperl-9.2' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-plperl-9.3' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-plperl-9.4' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-plperl-9.5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-plperl-9.6' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-plpython-10' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-plpython-8.4' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-plpython-9.0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-plpython-9.1' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-plpython-9.2' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-plpython-9.3' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-plpython-9.4' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-plpython-9.5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-plpython-9.6' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-plpython3-10' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-plpython3-9.1' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-plpython3-9.2' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-plpython3-9.3' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-plpython3-9.4' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-plpython3-9.5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-plpython3-9.6' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-pltcl-10' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-pltcl-8.4' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-pltcl-9.0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-pltcl-9.1' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-pltcl-9.2' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-pltcl-9.3' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-pltcl-9.4' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-pltcl-9.5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-pltcl-9.6' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-q3c' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-server-dev-10' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-server-dev-8.4' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-server-dev-9.0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-server-dev-9.1' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-server-dev-9.2' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-server-dev-9.3' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-server-dev-9.4' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-server-dev-9.5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-server-dev-9.6' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'postgresql-server-dev-all' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  comerr-dev krb5-multidev libgssrpc4 libisl10 libkadm5clnt-mit9
  libkadm5srv-mit9 libkdb5-7 libossp-uuid16 libqt5x11extras5
  linux-headers-4.4.0-31 linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic
  postgresql-9.3 postgresql-client-9.3 postgresql-client-common
  postgresql-common postgresql-contrib-9.3 qtdeclarative5-controls-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-quicklayouts-plugin
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 20 to remove and 323 not upgraded.
9 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 323 MB disk space will be freed.
(Reading database ... 331550 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing postgresql-contrib-9.3 (9.3.24-1.pgdg14.04+1) ...
Removing postgresql-9.3 (9.3.19-0ubuntu0.14.04) ...
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/postgresql not found.
dpkg: error processing package postgresql-9.3 (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 100
Removing postgresql-client-common (192.pgdg14.04+1) ...
Removing krb5-multidev (1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu5.3) ...
Removing comerr-dev (2.1-1.42.9-3ubuntu1.3) ...
Removing libkadm5srv-mit9:amd64 (1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu5.3) ...
Removing libkdb5-7:amd64 (1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu5.3) ...
Removing libkadm5clnt-mit9:amd64 (1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu5.3) ...
Removing libgssrpc4:amd64 (1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu5.3) ...
Removing libisl10:amd64 (0.12.2-1) ...
Removing libossp-uuid16 (1.6.2-1.3ubuntu1) ...
Removing libqt5x11extras5:amd64 (5.2.1-1) ...
Removing linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic (4.4.0-31.50~14.04.1) ...
Removing linux-headers-4.4.0-31 (4.4.0-31.50~14.04.1) ...
Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic (4.4.0-31.50~14.04.1) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-31-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-31-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.4.0-31-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.4.0-31-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-extlinux 4.4.0-31-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic
P: Checking for EXTLINUX directory... found.
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-98-generic.efi.signed...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-98-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-92-generic.efi.signed...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-92-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-135-generic...
P: Installing debian theme... done.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-31-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-98-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-98-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-92-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-92-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-135-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-135-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
Removing linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic (4.4.0-31.50~14.04.1) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-31-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-extlinux 4.4.0-31-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic
P: Checking for EXTLINUX directory... found.
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-98-generic.efi.signed...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-98-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-92-generic.efi.signed...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-92-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-135-generic...
P: Updating /boot/extlinux/linux.cfg...
P: Installing debian theme... done.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-31-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-98-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-98-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-92-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-92-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-135-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-135-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
Removing qtdeclarative5-controls-plugin:amd64 (5.2.1-2) ...
Removing qtdeclarative5-quicklayouts-plugin:amd64 (5.2.1-2) ...
dpkg: postgresql-common: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 postgresql-9.3 depends on postgresql-common (>= 142~); however:
  Package postgresql-common is to be removed.

Removing postgresql-common (192.pgdg14.04+1) ...
Removing 'diversion of /usr/bin/pg_config to /usr/bin/pg_config.libpq-dev by postgresql-common'
dpkg: postgresql-client-9.3: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 postgresql-9.3 depends on postgresql-client-9.3.

Removing postgresql-client-9.3 (9.3.24-1.pgdg14.04+1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for install-info (5.2.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
Processing triggers for doc-base (0.10.5) ...
Processing 1 removed doc-base file...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.13) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 postgresql-9.3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: I ended up using Harrypotter0's answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26571326/how-do-i-resolve-the-following-packages-have-unmet-dependencies?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can try step available in this link [How to remove Postgres from my installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32730/how-to-remove-postgres-from-my-installation) to first remove all your files of previously installed postgres
and then try to install a new one.

Comment: My experience from using the link you posted. First I ran "dpkg -l | grep postgres", which lists the remaining packages. It found four packages, one of which was "pgdg-keyring ". So I ran "sudo apt-get purge pgdg-keyring", but I receive the same dependency error: "The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql-9.3 : Depends: postgresql-client-9.3 but it is not going to be installed
"