# Problems when installing python3-dev

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, ubuntu, pip

This problem has been torturing me for 2 days, and without `python3-dev` I can't pip install any module, can someone tell how could I solve this?

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     python3-dev : Depends: python3 (= 3.5.1-3) but 3.5.1-4 is to be installed
                   Depends: libpython3-dev (= 3.5.1-3) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python3.5-dev (>= 3.5.1-2~) but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get install -f`?

Comment: What does `apt policy python3 python3-dev` output?

Comment: This is problem with the `apt` ubuntu/debian package manager being in an inconsistent state. The question belongs on the askubuntu stackexchange site.
[How do I resolve `The following packages have unmet dependencies`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26571326/how-do-i-resolve-the-following-packages-have-unmet-dependencies/35679746#35679746)

Comment: First of all run `apt update` after try `apt remove python3` and now try to install `python3-dev`.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to install package **libpython3-dev** instead of installing package python3-dev.

I have answered a similar question here:
https://superuser.com/a/1407453/1000196

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution like this for myself on Ubuntu Desktop 20.04:

Go to "Software & Updates" application -> Then change your "Download from" server to "Main server". After this close and go terminal. Then sudo apt update -y && sudo apt upgrade -y && sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt install python3-dev -y

Answer (score 0):

I met this issue, and I fixed it with steps below:

1. I tried to install libpython3-dev or python3.7-dev, it told me that "Depends: libexpat1-dev but it is not going to be installed"
2. So I tried to install libexpat1-dev, it told me that "Depends: libexpat1 (= 2.2.6-2+deb10u4) but 2.2.6-2+deb10u1 is to be installed"
3. Then I update libexpat1 version to 2.2.6-2+deb10u4 with command "sudo apt-get install libexpat1=2.2.6-2+deb10u4"
4. Next, I installed libexpat1-dev, python3.7-dev, python3-dev with command below:

```
sudo apt-get install libexpat1-dev
sudo apt-get install python3.7-dev
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```