# I get the error of the CXX compiler identification is unknown

Tags: cmake, compiler-errors, ubuntu-18.04

I get the following error when I try to use cmake to compile a source code:

$ sudo cmake -DUSE_QT5=1 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/linux/myYade ../trunk

-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:35 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.

Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/linux/myYade/trunk/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/linux/myYade/trunk/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

Any help to get this resolved?

Comment: It looks like that I do not have g++ but I cannot install it either. I tried to install it by sudo apt-get install g++ but I get an error:  The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 g++ : Depends: g++-7 (>= 7.3.0-12~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: So, the problem is not with CMake, but with `apt-get`. Have you tried to google for that error? E.g., look into given question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26571326/how-do-i-resolve-the-following-packages-have-unmet-dependencies/49041818.

Comment: Sure I did. But I'm more confused now. sudo apt-get update is also giving an error now:

Ign:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/yade-users/external/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Err:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/yade-users/external/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: ]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/yade-users/external/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Comment: Well, such problems with `apt-get` are more suitable for [ubuntu.se]: they are no a *programming* one, so Stack Overflow is a bad place for them.