# Unable to install mysqlclient with pip on ubuntu

Tags: python, mysql, django, ubuntu, pip

I'm trying to install mysqlclient on Ubuntu 20.04LTS, the main error is: mysql_config not found.

Whole Error:

```
$ pip3 install mysqlclient==2.0.3
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting mysqlclient==2.0.3
  Using cached mysqlclient-2.0.3.tar.gz (88 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-qr1hc7jz/mysqlclient_1ff152ec2d5d4f14a4e282285faeb229/setup.py'"'"'; _file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-qr1hc7jz/mysqlclient_1ff152ec2d5d4f14a4e282285faeb229/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file_) if os.path.exists(_file_) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, _file_, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-ehrlbbbl
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-qr1hc7jz/mysqlclient_1ff152ec2d5d4f14a4e282285faeb229/
  Complete output (15 lines):
  /bin/sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
  /bin/sh: 1: mariadb_config: not found
  /bin/sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-install-qr1hc7jz/mysqlclient_1ff152ec2d5d4f14a4e282285faeb229/setup.py", line 15, in <module>
      metadata, options = get_config()
    File "/tmp/pip-install-qr1hc7jz/mysqlclient_1ff152ec2d5d4f14a4e282285faeb229/setup_posix.py", line 70, in get_config
      libs = mysql_config("libs")
    File "/tmp/pip-install-qr1hc7jz/mysqlclient_1ff152ec2d5d4f14a4e282285faeb229/setup_posix.py", line 31, in mysql_config
      raise OSError("{} not found".format(_mysql_config_path))
  OSError: mysql_config not found
  mysql_config --version
  mariadb_config --version
  mysql_config --libs
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3c/df/59cd2fa5e48d0804d213bdcb1acb4d08c403b61c7ff7ed4dd4a6a2deb3f7/mysqlclient-2.0.3.tar.gz#sha256=f6ebea7c008f155baeefe16c56cd3ee6239f7a5a9ae42396c2f1860f08a7c432 (from https://pypi.org/simple/mysqlclient/) (requires-python:>=3.5). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysqlclient==2.0.3 (from versions: 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.3.8, 1.3.9, 1.3.10, 1.3.11rc1, 1.3.11, 1.3.12, 1.3.13, 1.3.14, 1.4.0rc1, 1.4.0rc2, 1.4.0rc3, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.2.post1, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.5, 1.4.6, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.1.0rc1, 2.1.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mysqlclient==2.0.3
```

(when trying to pip3 install mysqlclient, the same error apears, but every version tries to install)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+mysql_config%3A+not+found

Comment: @phd none of the above solutions seem to work for me

Answer (score 17):

You need to install the python3 and MySQL development headers and libraries like in your ubuntu OS,

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential
```

then install using

```
pip3 install mysqlclient==2.0.3
```

I hope this will help you out

Comment: When executing the first command it says that there are dependencies, but will not be installed (and if i try to install them they also have dependencies and for some reason they won't install recursively)

Comment: I have also faced the similar kind of issues better you should go with the latest version rather than specific one

Comment: this helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26571326/how-do-i-resolve-the-following-packages-have-unmet-dependencies