# VS code setting up development tools ERR! permission

Tags: npm

I'm new to using VS code, I'm trying to install Hubspot tools using the npm install -g @hubspot/cli

But when i do i get the following

Thorins-MBP:Practice project thorinphoenix$ npm install -g @hubspot/cli
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@hubspot
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@hubspot'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@hubspot'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@hubspot'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/thorinphoenix/.npm/_logs/2022-05-18T13_17_18_580Z-debug-0.log
Thorins-MBP:Practice project thorinphoenix$

Answer (score 0):

I used the best fix on this page and it worked. [How to fix EACCES issues with npm install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25290986/how-to-fix-eacces-issues-with-npm-install)

Enter this into terminal:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```